# Adjust UILabel according to the change in height of UITextview

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitextview, frame

I'm new to iOS  development
when UITextView changes its height dynamically (for example User enters more than one Line in UITextView) how to adjust UILabel position (which is below the uitextview) with respect the height of UITextView

[image]

```
        after text entered by user
```

[image]

Comment: When user enter more than one lines then UItextView frame will not change and you can see the whole text by scrolling inside that. So what you want exactly? Screenshot will be better for understanding

Comment: Do you want expandable label?

Comment: yes you are right. but i want to increase the height of UITextview according to the content.

Comment: if you want expandable hight of UILabel then after setting text to UILable, set numberOfLines = 0 and call sizeToFit method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not using auto layout, you can do it like this

```
CGRect rect = self.lbl.frame;
rect.origin.y = self.txtVw.frame.origin.y + self.txtVw.frame.size.height;
self.lbl.frame = rect;
```

Answer (score 0):

Or if you do use auto layouts, subclass UITextView and override couple methods in it like this:

```
- (void) layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    if (!CGSizeEqualToSize(self.bounds.size, [self intrinsicContentSize])) {
        [self invalidateIntrinsicContentSize];
    }
}

- (CGSize)intrinsicContentSize
{
    CGFloat boundWidth = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow].frame.size.width;
    boundWidth = MIN(boundWidth, self.bounds.size.width);
    CGSize intrinsicContentSize;
    intrinsicContentSize = [self sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(boundWidth, FLT_MAX)];
    return intrinsicContentSize;
}
```

Don't forget to assign your class for text view in Interface Builder and of course set all other constraints properly.
I think, I've found this solution somewhere on StackOverflow myself some time ago, sorry can't provide a link to the original answer.